# MyRoster Class is having some issues. specifically my sort method and removeNull method

Tags: java, class, data-structures, methods

I am trying to make a class called roster that takes a Student object and can add, remove, search, etc. all of my methods work except  I keep getting a nullPointerException when I call my sort class. Also, for some reason when I load the roster it prints the last element in the array twice. I think the two issues are related.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class Roster {
    
    private Object [] array = new Student [10];
    private LinkedList <Student> roster = new LinkedList<Student>();
    private int counter = 0;
    
    public Roster (Student student) {// O(1) this runs in constant time
        addStudent(student);
    }

    public Student[] getArray() {// O(1) this runs in constant time
        return (Student[]) array;
    }

    public void setArray(Student[] array) {// O(1) this runs in constant time
        this.array = array;
    }

    public LinkedList<Student> getRoster() { // O(1) this runs in constant time
        return roster;
    }

    public void setRoster(LinkedList<Student> roster) {// O(1) this runs in constant time
        this.roster = roster;
    }
    
    public Student[] sort() { //O(n^2) runs n^2 times for the nested for loop
        array = roster.toArray();
        
            for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) { // O(n)
                
                for(int j =1; j < array.length - i; j++) // O(n)
                if((((Student) array[j - 1]).compareTo((Student) array[j])) >= 1) {
                    Student temp = (Student) array[j-1];
                    array[j-1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        return (Student[]) array;
    } 

    public void loadRoster() { // O(n) executes the length of the array
        removeNull(array);
        for(int i =0; i< array.length -1; i++)
            System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    
    public void addStudent(Student student) { // O(n) toArray()
        if(counter == 10)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sorry the class is full");
        roster.add(student);
        array = roster.toArray();
        //sort((Student[]) array);
        counter++;
    }
    
    public void removeStudent(String ID) { // O(n) toArray()
        if(counter <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The class is empty");
        roster.remove(IDSearch(ID));
        array = roster.toArray();
        counter--;
    }
    public Object[] removeNull(Object[] tempArr) {
        
        int k = 0;
        for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] == null)
                    continue;
                tempArr[k] = (Student) array[i];
                k++;
        }
        return tempArr;         
    }

    public Student IDSearch( String IDNumber) {  // O(n) runs the for loop
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
            if(((Student) array[i]).getIDNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(IDNumber)) {
                System.out.print(array[i]);
                return (Student) array[i];
            }
        System.out.print("Student not found");
        return null;
    }
    
    public Student nameSearch(String lastName , String firstName) { // O(n) for loop for array length
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
            if((((Student) array[i]).getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName)) && (((Student) array[i]).getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))) {
                System.out.println(array[i]);
                return (Student) array[i];
            }
        System.out.print("Student not found");
        return null;    
    }
    
    public void save() { // constant time
        array = removeNull(array);
        sort();
    }

    public void saveChanges() throws FileNotFoundException{ // O(n) for loop to print to the new file
        save();
        File file = new File ("Roster.txt");
        
        if (file.exists())
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
        for(int i =0; i <array.length; i++)
            out.println(array[i]);
        
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get this `NullPointerException`? Please point out the line number and method call.

Answer (score 0):

In your sort function you run through the whole array of students, which may still contain null values. Note that array.length will give the size of the array not the number of set elements. I would recommend you make use of your removeNull() method to avoid this issue, or use the counter value instead of array.length in the for loops.

Comment: now the only issue is that for some reason it prints the last element in the array two times/ I think it is being stored two times

Comment: and for some reason, it only sorts the items that are originally placed into the array, not the items that were added after. even though those items get printed to the new file so they are in the array, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: In your setRoster/setArray methods you are not setting your counter variable. If you set the roster and then add two students and do a sort, it will only sort the first two students because counter == 2.

Comment: As for the sort printing last student twice, it looks like you are using bubble sort, correct? If so, you should change the second for loop to have j < counter - i - 1 instead of j < array.length - i. Post again if you still have any problems, and please upvote and accept my answer if it's been helpful!

Comment: these did not fix the problem, unfortunately. I think that the double printing has something to do with my removeNull  because if I don't call that method it prints the nulls but only prints each name from the list once